# Comparing two date columns in a single table

Tags: mysql, date, compare

One of tables in my database holds the `check_in_date` and `checkout_date` of a certain item. I'd like to create a trigger that doesn't allow updating the table if someone inputs a checkout date that is earlier than check-in date, for example if check-in = 2017-10-16, then 2017-10-14 checkout shouldn't be allowed. I read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-date.html and it says that when comparing two columns with date you should use `STRCMP`. So I tried, but it still accepts any dates. I'm probably using the `STRCMP` wrong, it should return -1 when the first argument is smaller, but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to use it in an if statement.

```
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS check_dates;
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER check_dates
    BEFORE UPDATE ON dates
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF STRCMP('NEW.checkout_date', 'check_in_date')=-1
        THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Checkout date must be after the checkin.';
        END IF;
    END;//
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `IF STRCMP('NEW.checkout_date', 'check_in_date')=-1` does not make sense at all. You need to compare the dates inside those fields and not the 2 strings

Comment: I think you should be preventing this from occurring at the app level, not the database.  Why aren't you doing this check before you insert?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's just a database for a school project, no app level :P The check out date isn't set, when I insert a new record it's usually NULL.
@juergend I tried just comparing dates by writing something along the lines of `IF NEW.checkout_date < check_in_date`, but then I get ERROR 1054(42S22): Unknown column 'check_in_date' in 'field list'. And if I compare by field value by adding ' ' then it just allows any date.

Comment: Try `IF NEW.checkout_date < check_in_date` and see if that works.

Comment: I was just editing my reply to @juergend, when I try to compare like that it gives me an error.

Comment: So I just fixed it by fiddling around with it randomly `IF NEW.checkout_date < NEW.check_in_date` works perfectly for some reason.

Comment: @Vendell I think you have forgot to select the `check_in_date` value from your table to which you need to compare new checkout_date.